# Bootstrap navbar-brand logo - portrait image has been cut off?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Following this [page](http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/logo-nav/) to use image logo instead of text for navbar brand, I came across this problem that the **portrait logo** has been cut off by any content/ text/ image/ carousal that comes after it.

How can I fix it?

```
<!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
<div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x200&text=Logo" alt="">
    </a>
</div>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Increase the height of the .navbar-header.

Comment: I need more details about the photo.  Can you publish a full HTML & CSS?

Answer (score 2):

Add a max-height to the img.

```
max-height: 100%;
height: 100%;
width: auto;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a z-index to your nav bar like so in your CSS file as it looks like your foreground image is overlapping it

```
.navbar-header {
   z-index: 100;

}
```

Comment: Then the navigation would be over the image. And the navigation isn't fixed so it would not make sense.

Comment: @LeonLaci the issue is that image is currently hidden behind the carousel once the z-index is applied you will see that image is there in full to make it look right afterwards they would need to readjust the navbar hight to give a clean look and the fact that navbar is not fixed means that once scrolled out of sight so will the image. however a  navigation with such height will be completely out of place